# How do I make a generic DAO interface in PHP?

Tags: java, php, dao

I'm trying to write a generic DAO interface in PHP. I know what it looks like in Java, but I only have an idea of what it looks like in PHP.

I've tried this in PHP.

```
<?php
 interface DAO {

    public function create($obj);
    public function read();
    public function update($obj);
    public function delete($obj);
 }
```

Because I want something like this Java interface

```
public interface DAO<T> {

    void create(T ob);
    List<T> read();
    void update(T ob);
    void delete(String id);

}
```

I expected to be able to just write the interface the same way I did in PHP, but I can't add the generic object to the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest form of a generic DAO is to provide the basic CRUD operations at an object level without exposing the internals of the persistence mechanism.

```
interface UserDao
{
    /**
     * Store the new user and assign a unique auto-generated ID.
     */
    function create($user);

    /**
     * Return the user with the given auto-generated ID.
     */
    function findById($id);

    /**
     * Return the user with the given login ID.
     */
    function findByLogin($login);

    /**
     * Update the user's fields.
     */
    function update($user);

    /**
     * Delete the user from the database.
     */
    function delete($user);
}
```